# Execute .command file through Java on Mac OS

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, runtime

I am making a program that involves executing a .command file on a Mac.

I used `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` to open the file (which works correctly).

The problem is that it says "The file could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges."

I tried doing this in the code before executing but it still shows this message:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod a+x " + new File(folder, "terminal.command").getPath());
```

I've tried `chmod a+x`, `chmod +x`, `chmod u+x`, and `chmod +X` and none have worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can start with running simple command line script from Terminal. Just make sure to create script, that has +x permission and is actually executable (e.g. starts with "#!/bin/bash")

Comment: @mko I’ve tried running this exact command (with an exact path not literally the “new File()” thing) in terminal and it worked.